# Override 'create' function in Django serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I wonder how to handle POST request to properly save the incoming data, having such models:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', related_name='recipes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.TextField(default='None')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(default='No description')
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    image = models.TextField(default='None')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    description = models.TextField(default='No description')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    unit_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I wanted to avoid duplicating Ingredient objects, so  to provide quantity of specific Ingredient in Recipe I've created a RecipesIngredient model that binds Ingredient with Recipe, but also contains a quantity of this Ingredient:

```
class RecipesIngredient(models.Model):
        recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, related_name='ingredients', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        quantity = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.quantity
```

I've also prepared some serializers for these models:

```
class IngredientSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = (
            'url',
            'image',
            'name',
            'description',
            'price',
            'unit_price',
            'unit_quantity'
        )

class RecipesIngredientSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ingredient_name = ReadOnlyField(source='ingredient.name')
    ingredient_price = ReadOnlyField(source='ingredient.price')
    ingredient_unit_price = ReadOnlyField(source='ingredient.unit_price')
    ingredient_unit_quantity = ReadOnlyField(source='ingredient.unit_quantity')

    class Meta:
        model = RecipesIngredient
        fields = (
            'url',
            'ingredient_name',
            'quantity',
            'ingredient_price',
            'ingredient_unit_price',
            'ingredient_unit_quantity'
        )

class RecipeListSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
    author_url = ReadOnlyField(source='author.url')

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = (
            'url',
            'author',
            'author_url',
            'image',
            'name',
            'description',
            'votes'
        )


class RecipeDetailSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
    author_url = ReadOnlyField(source='author.url')
    ingredients = RecipesIngredientSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = (
            'url',
            'author',
            'author_url',
            'image',
            'name',
            'description',
            'ingredients',
            'votes'
        )
```

But in this case, I have to first create a Recipe instance and save it to DB, then do the same with Ingredient to be able to "bind" them in RecipesIngredient. Is this possible to handle this case with only one POST request to view below?

```
#
# path('recipes/', views.RecipeList.as_view(), name='recipe-list')
#
class RecipeList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeListSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

@EDIT
I forgot 'bout this thread, but the problem is solved now. I've prepared another serializer for CREATE purposes only, and overridden the 'create' function of this serializer.:

```
class RecipeCreateSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    #author = ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
    #author_url = ReadOnlyField(source='author.url')
    recipes_ingredients = RecipesIngredientCreateSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        recipes_ingredients = validated_data.pop('recipes_ingredients')
        recipe_instance = super().create(validated_data)

        for recipe_ingredient in recipes_ingredients:

            ingredient_data = recipe_ingredient.pop('ingredient')
            ingredient_instance = Ingredient(
                image=ingredient_data['image'],
                name=ingredient_data['name'],
                description=ingredient_data['description'],
                price=ingredient_data['price'],
                unit_price=ingredient_data['unit_price'],
                unit_quantity=ingredient_data['unit_quantity'],
            )
            ingredient_instance.save()


            recipes_ingredient_instance = RecipesIngredient(
                recipe=recipe_instance,
                ingredient=ingredient_instance,
                quantity=recipe_ingredient['quantity']
            )
            recipes_ingredient_instance.save()
        return recipe_instance

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = (
            'url',
            'image',
            'name',
            'description',
            'votes',
            'recipes_ingredients',
        )
```

Also the JSON file looks a bit different now, but everything works just fine:

```
{
    "image": "image-url",
    "name": "recipes-name",
    "description": "recipes-description",
    "votes": 0,
    "recipes_ingredients": [
        {
            "quantity": "ingredients-quantity",
            "ingredient": {
                "image": "image-url",
                "name": ingredient-name",
                "description": "ingredient-description",
                "price": 3.6,
                "unit_price": 0.36,
                "unit_quantity": "100ML"
            }
        },
        {
            "quantity": "ingredients-quantity",
            "ingredient": {
                "image": "image-url",
                "name": ingredient-name",
                "description": "ingredient-description",
                "price": 0.3,
                "unit_price": 0.3,
                "unit_quantity": "EACH"
            }
        },
        {
            "quantity": "ingredients-quantity",
            "ingredient": {
                "image": "image-url",
                "name": ingredient-name",
                "description": "ingredient-description",
                "price": 2.0,
                "unit_price": 0.8,
                "unit_quantity": "KG"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with the POST request body ?

Comment: I do not have any. I mean, for this moment I send three separated requests for each endpoint. The one for Recipe, the second one for Ingredient and the last one for RecipesIngredient. I Just wanted to know how to prepare some function (on server side) that could take one request, and create an instance of each model in (for example) this order:
1. Take Recipe data from request and create Recipe instance
2. Take the Ingredients data and create Ingredients
3. Take RecipeIngredients data and create RecipesIngredients